Area with double integral in polar coordinates
Determine the area interior to $y^2=2ax-x^2$ and exterior to $y^2=ax$.
The area in artesian coordinates is $$\int_{0}^{a}\int_{\sqrt{ax}}^{\sqrt{2ax-x^2}} dydx$$. To convert it into polar coordinates with the jacobian $r$,we need to find the limits of $r$ and $\theta$. How to find the limits in our desired region?

I have some confusion about the limits of the angle which the answers confirm to be $45$ and $90$. The way areas are added in polar coordinates is by adding differential sectors of circles or little triangles which I have marked in blue. If the lower limit is $45$,then any small sector will have an unintended area which is not the same as our desired area(which is marked in violet). So don't we have to subtract the areas?

Fine. Have you tried to substitute polar coordinates into existing inequalities?

The curve with equation $y^2=ax$ isn't closed; so what does “exterior” to it mean?

Also, are you ignoring the lower half of the plane?

Having $\sqrt{ax} \leqslant y \leqslant \sqrt{2ax-x^2}$ and substituting in it polar coordinates gives $\frac{a\cos \phi}{\sin^2 \phi} \leqslant r \leqslant 2a \cos \phi$. So we obtain
$$\int\limits_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int\limits_{\frac{a\cos \phi}{\sin^2 \phi}}^{2a \cos \phi}rdrd\phi$$
limits for $\phi$ is easy to view from drawing area, but can you obtain it formally from the same inequalities?
Addition.
From above inequalities we have $\cos \phi \geqslant 0$ and $\sin \phi \geqslant 0$, which together gives desired.

I don't understand how the limit for the angle starts from $0$. Clearly the intersection points of our desired region don't lie on the x axis. Could you please share which region you are working on?

One intersection point, in Cartesian coordinates, is $(0,0)$, so it is on x axis.

Could you kindly elaborate a bit more on the angle limit? I can't understand it intuitively. Thanks in advance

I just noticed that I had a typo in limits for angle - lower should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$. The angles must be $[\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2}]$ as given by the inequalities $\sin \phi \geqslant 0, \cos \phi \geqslant 0$ indicated in the answer. If you doubted the $0$ limit, then you were right.

Area in blue color is not in our figure, only violet, if I correctly understand you.

OP's picture implies that, but the problem statement quoted by OP doesn't. Whichever is more representative of OP's actual problem determines whether the factor is 1 or 2.

(This answer is essentially the same as @zkutch's; I'm just trying to fill in some details.)
To find the limits of integration in polar coordinates, it helps to convert the equations of the bounding curves.
The first curve has equation
$$\begin{aligned}
    r^2\sin^2\theta &= 2a r\cos \theta - r^2 \cos^2 \theta
\\\implies r^2\sin^2\theta + r^2 \cos^2 \theta &= 2a r\cos \theta
\\\implies r^2 &= 2ar\cos\theta
\\\implies r &= 2a\cos\theta
\end{aligned}$$
The second curve has equation
$$\begin{aligned}
    r^2 \sin^2\theta &= a r \cos\theta
\\\implies    r &= a \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta} = a \cot \theta \csc \theta
\end{aligned}$$
(We're ignoring the trivial $r=0$ solutions.)
Where do these curves intersect? Since you have $r$ in terms of $\theta$, set the two expressions of $\theta$ equal to each other:
$$
    2a \cos\theta = a \frac{\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta}
    \implies a\cos\theta(2 \sin^2\theta -1) = 0
$$
This is satisfied when $\cos\theta = 0$ or $\sin^2\theta = \frac{1}{2}$.
The first implies $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ (and $r=0$), and the second implies that $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ or $\theta = \frac{7\pi}{4}$ (and $r=a\sqrt{2}$). In cartesian coordinates, these points are $(0,0)$ and $(a,\pm a)$. By symmetry, we can restrict to the first quadrant and double the result. This gives us the limits $\frac{\pi}{4} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore the area is
$$
    2\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{a \cot\theta\csc\theta}^{2a\cos\theta} r\,dr\,d\theta = \left(\frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{4}{3}\right)a^2
$$
(Wolfram Alpha link)
The lower limit of the $\theta$ integral is what prevents us from counting that “unintended area” you shaded in blue. You could write the area as a difference of integrals as in
$$
    2 \left(\int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{2a\cos\theta} r\,dr\,d\theta - \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \int_{0}^{a \cot\theta\csc\theta} r\,dr\,d\theta\right)
$$
But that evaluates to the same thing. In general, whenever $a < c < b$, then $\int_b^c f(x)\,dx = \int_a^c f(x)\,dx - \int_a^b f(x)\,dx$.
